# Why front end of the python web application throws an exception?

Tags: python, pandas, callback, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am building a python web application to show a gold price movement in a time-series graph. But my callbacks are not working and it throws the following exception in the front end of the application.

```
ID not found in layout
6:42:46 AM
Attempting to connect a callback Input item to component:
  "none"
but no components with that id exist in the layout.

If you are assigning callbacks to components that are
generated by other callbacks (and therefore not in the
initial layout), you can suppress this exception by setting
`suppress_callback_exceptions=True`.
This ID was used in the callback(s) for Output(s):
  this_year_graph.figure
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output
from datetime import datetime

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"

req = Request(url=url)
html_content = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
df = pd.read_html(url)  # this will give you a list of dataframes from html

df1 = df[3]

first_val = df1.iloc[0][0]

date = df1[0]
price = df1[1]
data = [df1[0],df1[1]]
headers = ["Date", "Price"]

df3 = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)

df3['Date'] = df3['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))
df3['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).year
df3['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).month
df3['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).day
df3['WDay'] = df3['Date'].dt.dayofweek
df3['WeekDayName'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).day_name()

print(df3['WDay'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Gold Price Analyst" , style={'text-align' : 'center'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='this_year_graph', figure={})
])

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='this_year_graph', component_property='figure')],
    [Input('none', 'children')]
)
def update_graph():
    dff = df3.copy()
    dff = [df4['Date'],df4['Price']]

    this_year_graph = px.line(dff , x=dff['Date'], y=dff['Price'])

    return fig

if __name__ =='__main__' :
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your callback function. The `@app.callback`'s `Input` tells, the app which element (button) should *run* this callback. Dash tries to find an HTML element with `id="none"` in your case.

```py
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='this_year_graph', component_property='figure')],
    [Input('none', 'children')]                       #### <<<<< HERE
)
def update_graph():
    dff = df3.copy()
    dff = [df4['Date'],df4['Price']]

    this_year_graph = px.line(dff , x=dff['Date'], y=dff['Price'])

    return fig
```

Insert a Button, or something else in your layout. And connect the callback to it.